# The work I am doing at my new job is not what I signed up for

Tags: management, communication, colleagues, work-experience, contracts

I recently started a new job as an Merchandiser at a small fashion supplier business. However all I have done is QC work and no merchandising since I have started which is 1 month and 1 week.

I have spoke of my concerns to the head twice but nothing seems to change.
Both times I was told to give it a couple of weeks as it has been hectic but still nothing. A Senior Merchandiser also started at the same time and she does seem to distribute the work fairly and speaking to her was a waste too.

The most unfortunate part was that I had this company and another to choose from and now regret not having chosen the other.

I really don't know what to do as I feel frustrated and not happy.

Comment: Is this your first job? Or have you had experience as a Merchandiser before? Are you the office junior? And what is the actual role of a Merchandiser?

Answer (score 3):

**Consider Giving it More Time**
 In my experience, it certainly can take a couple of months to really settle into a job. The work you're doing now may be giving you good background experience that will be required for the job you were hired for, or your supervisors may be starting you with slightly different work and evaluating your performance. I would give it a couple of months before escalating your concerns further.

**If There's Still No Change**
It's good that you've spoken to your supervisors this early. They should definitely be the first stop for something like this. If nothing changes in the near future, they should be the first ones you talk to then also.

If your company is large enough to have an HR department, you could also make a stop there and talk to them about it to.

No matter who you're speaking to about this, make sure you have very clear descriptions of the job you were expecting and of what the job currently entails. If you can find it, consider taking a copy of the original job posting with its description into these meetings so you can substantiate your claims.

Unfortunately, if neither of these outlets resolves your concerns, it may be time to start a new job search. I know that leaving a job after only a few months may reflect poorly, but in interviews you should be able to explain that the job wasn't what you expected without it being held against you. Just try to keep a positive spin on it. Emphasize good points of the job and lessons you learned from it. You can also use it as a way to start a discussion of exactly what you *are* looking for to try to prevent it from happening again.

**Other Complaints**
Regarding the unfair work distribution, that is an entirely separate issue that should be handled separately. Try to leave that out of the conversations about the types of duties you're being assigned.

Comment: Agreed - one month is pretty short time into a new position - most of my first few months as an Engineer involved stitching graphics together in Paint - it wasn't exactly the kind of work I'd expected after building robots at university - but then I realised that I was learning about the systems that the graphics represented and how they linked up so I was ready to get on and start being an Engineer for the company.

Answer (score 2):

> I really don't know what to do as I feel frustrated and not happy.

You haven't been there very long - perhaps not long enough to know if this is a temporary situation, or if this is what your manager expects you to do long-term. Many companies have stretches where people need to pitch in and do work that isn't their "core" for short periods of time.

With a bit more time it will become clearer - then decision will become clearer.

If you decide to leave, I suggest finding your next job first, then quitting, rather than the other way around. You'll make better decisions about your next job (and perhaps research them enough to know if you'll be doing work more to your liking) if you aren't under financial pressure to find a job quickly.

Comment: And even if you decide to find a new job, make sure you do the work you are assigned well. If you are not, then that may be part of the reason they don't trust you with the more interesting work.  And at least you will be building a decent refernce even if you are there a short time.  But honestly all jobs have some work that one would rather not do. You still have to do it unless you are a world-renowned expert in a very tiny field..